# Unidirectional ElGamal Proxy Re-Encryption implementation

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, modular-arithmetic, elgamal

I've implemented an ElGamal scheme in JavaScript (the code is awful, just wanted to test it quick) based on [this](https://www.di-mgt.com.au/public-key-crypto-discrete-logs-3-elgamal.html) explanation.

```
var forge = require('node-forge');
var bigInt = require("big-integer");

var bits = 160;
forge.prime.generateProbablePrime(bits, function(err, num) {
  // Create prime factor and convert to bigInt
  var factor = bigInt(num.toString(10));
  // Find a larger prime of which factor is prime factor
  // Determine a large even number as a co-factor
  var coFactor = bigInt.randBetween("2e260", "3e260"); // should be bitLength(prime) - bitLength(factor)
  var prime = 4;
  while(!coFactor.isEven() || !prime.isPrime()) {
    coFactor = bigInt.randBetween("2e260", "3e260"); // should be bitLength(prime) - bitLength(factor)
    prime = coFactor.multiply(factor);
    prime = prime.add(1);
  }
  // Get a generator g for the multiplicative group mod factor
  var j = prime.minus(1).divide(factor);
  var h = bigInt.randBetween(2, prime.minus(1));
  var g = h.modPow(j, factor);
  // Alice's keys
  // Secret key
  var a = bigInt.randBetween(2, factor.minus(2));
  // Public key
  var A = g.modPow(a, prime);
  // Bob's keys
  // Secret key
  var b = bigInt.randBetween(2, factor.minus(2));
  // Public key
  var B = g.modPow(b, prime);
  // Shared secret
  // Calculated by Alice
  var Sa = B.modPow(a, prime);
  // Calculated by Bob
  var Sb = A.modPow(b, prime);
  // Check
  // Encryption by Alice
  var k = bigInt.randBetween(1, factor.minus(1));
  var c1 = g.modPow(k, prime);
  // Using Bob's public key
  var m = bigInt(2234266) // our message
  var c2 = m.multiply(B.modPow(k, prime));
  // Decryption by Bob
  var decrypt = c1.modPow((prime.minus(b).minus(bigInt(1))), prime).multiply(c2).mod(prime);
  console.log(decrypt); // should be 2234266
```

This seems to be working, the decryption step in the end returns the original number. I now wanted to convert this into a unidirectional proxy re-encryption scheme based on the following idea, taken from [this](https://www.isoc.org/isoc/conferences/ndss/03/proceedings/papers/14.pdf) paper (page 6, left column).

So you don't have to read the paper, the logic behind it is that we can split a private key `x` in two parts `x1` and `x2` such that `x = x1 + x2`. A proxy would get `x1` and decrypt with `x1`, passing the result to the end user, which would decrypt with `x2`. The following picture describes the math in more detail for the first by the proxy, using `x1`.

[image: Convertion to unidirection ElGamal]

where:

- m = plaintext message
- g = generator of the group
- r = integer chosen at random from Zq
- x = secret key

The next step would be for the proxy to pass that to the end user which would use x2 to get the plaintext m (the functioning is analogous to the one above).

Now, I've tried implementing this by adding to the code

```
  // Proxy re-encryption test
  // x is secret key
  var x = bigInt.randBetween(1, factor.minus(1));
  var x1 = bigInt.randBetween(1, x);
  var x2 = x.minus(x1);
  // y is public key
  var y = g.modPow(x, prime);
  var r = bigInt.randBetween(1, factor.minus(1));
  var c3 = g.modPow(r, prime);
  // mg^xr
  var c4 = bigInt(2234266).multiply(y.modPow(r, prime));

  var _decryptP = c4.divide(g.modPow(x1.multiply(r), prime));
  var _decryptF = _decryptP.divide(g.modPow(x2.multiply(r), prime));
});
```

by following the same logic as in the equation above. However, `_decryptF` does not return `2234266` as it should. Strangely, it always returns 0.

My question is: can anyone see where this is going wrong?

Comment: You're saying just in the `_decryptP` and `_decryptF`, correct? I tried that but that still does not give me the correct value. It either throws an error at `_decryptP` saying the two large numbers are not co-prime or just gives back the wrong value. Any ideas? Thanks a lot for helping with this.

Comment: That makes sense but in terms of the math it's the same, correct? My thinking is that if c3 = g^r then `c3.modPow(x1, prime)` = (g^r)^x1 which is the same as `g.modPow(x1.multiply(r), prime)` = g^(x1r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two problems:

- `divide` divides two numbers. Since both numbers are large, it is unlikely that the divident is a multiple of the divisor so you will always get 0 as a result. Modular division is actually a multiplication with the modular inverse. So, `a / b` is actually meant as `a * (b-1 (mod p)) (mod p)` .
- `multiply` multiplies two numbers. It is possible and likely that you jump out of the group using this function (I mean you can get a number larger or equal to `prime`). You have to apply the `mod` operation on the result. Technically, you only need to do this for the last `multiply`, but doing it for the intermediate steps considerably improves performance, because the numbers are smaller.

Here is the resulting code that works:

```
  // Proxy re-encryption test
  // x is secret key
  var x = bigInt.randBetween(1, factor.minus(1));
  var x1 = bigInt.randBetween(1, x);
  var x2 = x.minus(x1);
  // y is public key
  var y = g.modPow(x, prime);
  var r = bigInt.randBetween(1, factor.minus(1));
  var c3 = g.modPow(r, prime);
  // mg^xr
  var c4 = m.multiply(y.modPow(r, prime)).mod(prime);

  var _decryptP = c4.multiply(c3.modPow(x1, prime).modInv(prime)).mod(prime);
  var _decryptF = _decryptP.multiply(c3.modPow(x2, prime).modInv(prime)).mod(prime);
  console.log(_decryptF); // should be 2234266
});
```

[Full code](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/a704347f6ee692e8bf4885700a43624f)

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the explanation (new to this stuff so it really helped to clear some doubts).